# Axios - Handle request with auto-set cookies

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, axios

I have request which by purpose is sending cookie with token. Here is how it looks-like in Postman:

[image]

As you can see in Cookies I receive the token I need to be set in browser. If I open the link from Postman request in browser I get cookie set:
[image]

When I use this request with Axios in my code, the cookie is not set in the browser. I am suspecting that I am not using it correctly. What I do is I am calling the method:

```
axios
      .get(`${apiAddress}Users?email=${logEmail}&password=${logPass}`)
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.status === 200) {
         console.log(res.data)
        }
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e)
      });
```

In this way of use, is it possible this method to set the cookie? Am I doing it right?
If the link is setting cookie when it is opened in browser with correct parameters why it is not working when it is called with Axios?

Comment: You need to set `withCredentials: true` for cookies to be allowed "cross origin" (and sent if set) - see [axios documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config)

Comment: @Bravo You are talking about the backend where request is created or axios.get('some api url', {withCredentials: true});

Comment: the request is not created on the backend ... it's created when you call `axios.get` - and yes, you need to set `withCredentials: true` for the request (i.e. in the browser, because I posted a link to axios, and you're using axios in the browser)

Comment: @Bravo I am getting: Access to XMLHttpRequest at [my_url_request] from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

Comment: the backend needs to handle CORS properly